# Linking queries error code 1052

Tags: mysql-error-1052

I am getting error code 1052 Column FireStationHome in field list is ambiguous when trying to equijoin two tables together in a query

This is the code I am using below:

```
SELECT FiremanID, FiremanHomeStation,StationPhone
FROM FIRE_REPORT AS F, FIRE_STATION AS FS
WHERE F.FiremanHomeStation = FS.FiremanHomeStation
AND StationPhone ='703';
```

From reading through the forums I am understanding that I need to link the first relation by a linking key.  FiremanHomeStation is the only linking key that I need to run the following directions.

Display FiremanID, FiremanHomeStation, and phone number of the station for all firefighters whose numbers begin with '703'.

Using the Boyce Codd Method I have normalized the following

```
FIRE_REPORT(FireID,Alarms,Address,FiremanID,FiremanName,FiremanPhone,FiremanHomeStation,StationAddress,StationPhone,TruckID,LicensePlate)
```

The rules:

> Each Fire can have several firefighters assigned to it
>  Each fire
>   can have several fire trucks assigned to it
>  Each firefighter can
>   be assigned to several fires
>  Each fire truck and be assigned to
>   several fires
>  Each Firefighter has a single home station
>  Each
>   station is unique
>  Each station has a single phone number

primary keys

```
FireID, FiremanID, FiremanHomeStation,TruckID

FireID -> Alarms, Address
FiremanID -> FiremanName, FiremanPhone, FiremanHomeStation
FiremanHomeStation -> StationAddress, StationPhone
TruckID -> LicensePlate
```

FIRE_REPORT(**FireID, FiremanID, FiremanHomeStation, TruckID**)
FIRE(***FireID***, Alarms, Address)
FIREMAN_ID(***FiremanID***, FiremanName, FiremanPhone)
FIRE_STATION(***FiremanHomeStation***, StationAddress, StationPhone)
TRUCK(***TruckID***, LicensePlate)

Referential integrity constraints
FireID in FIRE_REPORT must exist in FireID in FIRE
FiremanID in FIRE_REPORT must exist in FiremanID in FIREMAN_ID
FiremanHomeStation in FIRE_REPORT must exist in FiremanHomeStation in FIRE_STATION
TruckID in FIRE_REPORT must exist in TruckID in TRUCK

```
create schema project_george;<br>
use project_george;<br>

CREATE TABLE FIRE   (<br>
    FireID int(3) NOT NULL,<br>
    Alarms int(1) NOT NULL,<br>
    Address varChar(25) NOT NULL,<br>
        CONSTRAINT FIRE_PK PRIMARY KEY(FireID),<br>
        CONSTRAINT FIRE_FR_FK FOREIGN KEY(FireID)<br>
        REFERENCES FIRE_REPORT(FireID)<br>
        ON UPDATE CASCADE<br>
);<br>
CREATE TABLE FIREMAN_ID (<br>
    FiremanID int(3) NOT NULL,<br>
    FiremanName varchar(25) NOT NULL,<br>
    FiremanPhone char(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,<br>
        CONSTRAINT FI_PK PRIMARY KEY(FiremanID),<br>
        CONSTRAINT FI_FR_FK FOREIGN KEY(FiremanID)<br>
        REFERENCES FIRE_REPORT(FiremanID)<br>
        ON UPDATE CASCADE<br>
);<br>
CREATE TABLE FIRE_STATION   (<br>
    FiremanHomeStation varChar(25) NOT NULL UNIQUE,<br>
    StationAddress varChar(25) NOT NULL,<br>
    StationPhone char(10) NOT NULL,<br>
        CONSTRAINT FS_PK PRIMARY KEY(FiremanHomeStation),<br>
        CONSTRAINT FS_FR_FK FOREIGN KEY(FiremanHomeStation)<br>
        REFERENCES FIRE_REPORT(FiremanHomeStation)<br>
        ON UPDATE CASCADE<br>
);<br>
CREATE TABLE TRUCK  (<br>
    TruckID int(3) NOT NULL,<br>
    LicensePlate char(5) NOT NULL UNIQUE,<br>
            CONSTRAINT TRUCK_PK PRIMARY KEY(TruckID),<br>
            CONSTRAINT TRUCK_RC_FK FOREIGN KEY(TruckID)<br>
            REFERENCES FIRE_REPORT(TruckID)<br>
            ON UPDATE CASCADE<br>
);<br>

CREATE TABLE FIRE_REPORT    (<br>
    FireID  int(3)  NOT NULL,<br>
    FiremanID int(3) NOT NULL,<br>
    FiremanHomeStation varChar(25) NOT NULL,<br>
    TruckID int(3) NOT NULL,<br>
        CONSTRAINT FR_PK PRIMARY KEY(FireID,FiremanID,FiremanHomeStation,TruckID),<br>
        CONSTRAINT FR_F_FK FOREIGN KEY (FireID)<br>
        REFERENCES FIRE(FireID) <br>
            ON UPDATE CASCADE,<br>
        CONSTRAINT FR_FID_FK FOREIGN KEY(FiremanID)<br>
        REFERENCES FIREMAN_ID(FiremanID)<br>
            ON UPDATE CASCADE,<br>
        CONSTRAINT FR_FS_FK FOREIGN KEY(FiremanHomeStation)<br>
        REFERENCES FIRE_STATION(FiremanHomeStation)<br>
            ON UPDATE CASCADE,<br>
        CONSTRAINT FR_TRUCK_FK FOREIGN KEY(TruckID)<br>
        REFERENCES TRUCK(TruckID)<br>
            ON UPDATE CASCADE<br>
);<br><br>

INSERT INTO FIRE VALUES(100, 1, '4025 Medford dr, Annandale VA 22003');<br>
INSERT INTO FIRE VALUES(101, 2, '7031 Little River Turnpike Suite 5A
Annandale, VA 22003-5958');<br>
INSERT INTO FIRE VALUES(102, 3, '7001 Little River Turnpike, Annandale, VA 22003 ');<br>
INSERT INTO FIRE VALUES(103, 4, '8333 Little River Turnpike Annandale, VA 22003');<br>
INSERT INTO FIRE VALUES(104, 5, '1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW  Washington, DC 20500');<br><br>

INSERT INTO FIREMAN_ID VALUES(100, 'Guliza Ormuzokova', '703-221-9918');<br>
INSERT INTO FIREMAN_ID VALUES(101, 'Lex Steele', '703-911-4450');<br>
INSERT INTO FIREMAN_ID(FiremanID,FiremanName,FiremanPhone) VALUES(102, 'George Putnam', '703-222-9918');<br>
INSERT INTO FIREMAN_ID VALUES(103, 'Steven Drasner', '571-939-1234');<br>
INSERT INTO FIREMAN_ID VALUES(104, 'Judy Miller', '571-999-1234');<br>
INSERT INTO FIREMAN_ID VALUES(105, 'Lily Thai', '703-911-4451');<br><br>

INSERT INTO FIRE_STATION VALUES('Station 29', '571 Broad st
Fairfax VA 22030', '703-200-9918');<br>
INSERT INTO FIRE_STATION VALUES('Station 229', '8914 Little River Turnpike, Fairfax, VA 22031 ', '703-900-4450');<br>
INSERT INTO FIRE_STATION VALUES('Station 429', '3988 University Dr, Fairfax, VA 22030 ', '571-900-1234');<br><br>

INSERT INTO TRUCK VALUES(1, 'burn29');<br>
INSERT INTO TRUCK VALUES(2, 'burn19');<br>
INSERT INTO TRUCK VALUES(3, 'burn09');<br><br>

/************I can't figure this on out!!!*** *****/<br>
SELECT FiremanID, FiremanHomeStation,StationPhone<br>
FROM FIRE_REPORT AS F, FIRE_STATION AS FS<br>
WHERE F.FiremanHomeStation = FS.FiremanHomeStation<br>
AND StationPhone ='703';<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

FiremanHomeStation is existing in both table but you don't specify from which table you want the result, which is ambiguous.

```
SELECT FiremanID, FS.FiremanHomeStation,StationPhone
FROM FIRE_REPORT AS F, FIRE_STATION AS FS
WHERE F.FiremanHomeStation = FS.FiremanHomeStation
AND StationPhone ='703';
```

Should work